# force jsoup use proxy and if proxy is offline dont use real ip

Tags: java, proxy, jsoup

```
 System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "<proxyip>"); // set proxy server
 System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "<proxyport>");  //set proxy port
 Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://your.url.here").get(); // Jsoup now connects via proxy
```

ok so problem with this is next:
i try to connect to website x with proxy but it looks like if proxy is offline jsoup tried to connect to website via my real ip but i dont want this 
how can i force use of proxy and if proxy is offline .. just dont connect to website

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. And i resolve doing this.

```
Proxy proxy;
                proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(host, Integer.parseInt(port)));
                URL url = new URL("http://google.es");
                URLConnection connect = url.openConnection(proxy);

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connect.getInputStream()));

                String tmp;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while ((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(tmp);
                }
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sb.toString());
```